# Sequelize association incorrect

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I want to build such relation:
[erd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDxpU.png)

I want each User to containt list of messages and each message to contain information about sender. Relevant to ERD that I posted.

Code that I have for migrations:

```
    module.exports = {
      up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
        queryInterface.createTable('Messages', {
          id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          },
          text: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
          },
          toUserId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            // TODO changed from CASCADE - not sure about change
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            references: {
              model: 'Users',
              key: 'id',
              as: 'toUserId',
            },
          },
          fromUserId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            // TODO changed from CASCADE - not sure about change
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            references: {
              model: 'Users',
              key: 'id',
              as: 'fromUserId',
            },
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
        }),
      down: (queryInterface /* , Sequelize */) =>
        queryInterface.dropTable('Messages'),
    };

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lat: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      lng: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      },
    }),
  down: (queryInterface /* , Sequelize */) => queryInterface.dropTable('Users'),
};
```

And for models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lat: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    lng: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    },
  });

  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Message, {
      foreignKey: 'toUserId',
      as: 'messages',
    });
  };

  return User;
};
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Message = sequelize.define('Message', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    text: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
  });

  Message.associate = (models) => {
    Message.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'toUserId',
    });
  };
  return Message;
};
```

However when I try to add new message fromUserId appears as Null value.
When I try to get messages, it looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "mytext",
        "createdAt": "2018-11-29T20:12:22.253Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-29T20:12:22.253Z",
        "toUserId": 2,
        "User": {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "name1",
            "lastName": "name2",
            "lat": null,
            "lng": null,
            "createdAt": "2018-11-29",
            "updatedAt": "2018-11-29"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your `ERD` I think your `relationships` should be some thing like this.

**User has many messages**

**Message belongs to user**
In that case your `Message` migration should be something like this.

```
id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          },
          text: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
          },
          fromUserId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            // TODO changed from CASCADE - not sure about change
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            references: {
              model: 'Users',
              key: 'id',
            },
          },
```

Note that I removed `toUserId` column and this alias `as: 'fromUserId',` too.

In your `User` migration, **it's correct** you don't need to change anything in there.

In your `Message` model

```
  Message.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'fromUserId',
    });
  };
```

Note that you have only one `FK` and it is `fromUserId`

In your `User` model.

```
User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Message, {
      foreignKey: 'fromUserId',
    });
  };
```

After doing all of this you will be able to get the messages belongs to a `user_id`.